# Which would be correct . . . there doesn't seem to be, or there aren't . .

Tags: word-usage

Which would be correct . . . there doesn't seem to be, or there aren't . . .

There doesn't seem to be any records.

There aren't any records.

Comment: When in doubt, always use the less complex form.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself which of the two sentences would be an acceptable answer to you.
If I need to know whether or not the "records" I'm looking for are at a particular location, and the file clerk tells me "there doesn't seem to be any records", I'm going to go look for another clerk that can tell me with certainty "there aren't any records". 
I might find it interesting if the first clerk used an upwards inflexion, as if they're surprised that "there doesn't seem to be any records". But usually people speak that way to avoid taking ownership of the statement.